# Multiselect table view controller items for email attachment

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Here is my XCode 4.3.2 problem...  I have a table displaying multi-select NSArray data in a table controller. I would like to select multiple items in the table, click a button on the bottom of the view controller, and attach the selected documents in the project that are referenced in the table's NSArray to an email message.  I have the email portion working ok, but not attaching anything. I also have the multi-select check marks working correctly.  Any ideas on getting multi-select attachment accomplished? I assume I have to build a mutableArray in which the table data cell text = the local PDF file name.???

Here is some of my code that I think will have to be edited for building the array?

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
if ([selectedCell accessoryType] == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone) {
    [selectedCell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
    [selectedIndexes addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row]];
    NSLog(@"Items I selected @ %d:", indexPath.row);
    NSLog(@"Items I selected: %@", selectedIndexes);
} else {
    [selectedCell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
    [selectedIndexes removeObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row]];
    NSLog(@"Items I de-selected @ %d:", indexPath.row);
}
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
```

}

The mail component:

```
- (IBAction)sendMailButton:(id)sender {
{
    if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
    {
        MFMailComposeViewController *mailer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc]      init];

        mailer.mailComposeDelegate = self;

        [mailer setSubject:@"Documentation Attached"];
        [mailer setMessageBody:@"Attached are documents from staff." isHTML:NO];

                   //[mailer setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];

        //iPad presentation enhancement:
        mailer.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPageSheet;

        [self presentModalViewController:mailer animated:YES];


    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                        message:@"Your device doesn't support the composer sheet"
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];

    }
}
```

}